# how to setup the redirect url for Slack?

Tags: slack

I have created a slack app and stuck at adding the redirect url. I want information like token, team_id from redirect url. I went through the link https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2 I got the idea of redirect url, but how should I create although I used client_id,secret in the url but I want to capture the HTTP request response. How should I create one?